# What is the origin of this error in my Discord bot code?

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I'm stuck with this, can you help me find the origin of the error? What I've tried so far: Posting this question to StackOverflow.

But seriously, it looks like it's an error in YoutubeDL; I'm not sure why this is happening. The code:

```
@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, url):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    voice_client = get(bot.voice_clients , guild = ctx.guild)

    if voice_client == None:
        await ctx.channel.send("Joined")
        await channel.connect()
        voice_client = get(bot.voice_clients , guild = ctx.guild)

    YDL_OPTIONS = {'format : bestaudio', 'noplaylist : True'}
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}


    if not voice_client.is_playing():
        with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
        URL = info['formats'][0]['url']
        voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(URL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
        voice_client.is_playing()
    else:
        await ctx.channel.send("Song has already played")
        return
```

Here's the trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Turbo349-PC\Desktop\discord-bot\discord-bot\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "discord-bot.py", line 69, in play
    with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
  File "C:\Users\Turbo349-PC\Desktop\discord-bot\discord-bot\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._screen_file = [sys.stdout, sys.stderr][params.get('logtostderr', False)]
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'get'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Turbo349-PC\Desktop\discord-bot\discord-bot\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Turbo349-PC\Desktop\discord-bot\discord-bot\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Turbo349-PC\Desktop\discord-bot\discord-bot\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `YDL_OPTIONS` is malformed: Instead of providing a `dict` you're providing a `set` because you've placed the colons inside of strings.

Instead of `{'format : bestaudio', 'noplaylist : True'}` you want the -- subtly different, but crucially totally other data structure -- `YDL_OPTIONS = {"format": "bestaudio", "noplaylist": True}`.